# Issues with a 3 list combination into one dictonary

Tags: python, python-2.7

Question is how would I combine three list's together while iterating through them.

## To explain it:

```
list_a has a bunch of the same keys
list_b has values
list_c has values
*Do the list have to be in order and what if they aren't????
```

## Here are my list:

```
#list_a would be the key  

list_a = ['MACHINE TOOLS', 'MACHINE TOOLS', 'FLUID', 'MACHINE TOOLS','MACHINE TOOLS', 'VALVES', 'FLUID', 'VALVES']

list_b = ['GROUP A MTOOLS', 'GROUP B MTOOLS', 'GROUP C MTOOLS', 'GROUP D MTOOLS', 'GROUP A FLUID', 'GROUP B FLUID', 'GROUP A VALVES', 'GROUP B VALVES'] 

list_c = ['1', '2', '3', '44', '46', '47', '52', '53']
```

## here is what I would like to see come out of this

```
{
    'MACHINE TOOLS': { 'GROUP A MTOOLS': '1', 'GROUP B MTOOLS': '2', 'GROUP C MTOOLS': '3', 'GROUP D MTOOLS': '44'}, 

    'FLUID': {'GROUP A FLUID': '46', 'GROUP B FLUID': '47'},

    'VALVES': {'GROUP A VALVES': '52', 'GROUP B VALVES': '53'}

}
```

## What I've tried:

```
dic={ list_as:{ list_bs:[list_c] for list_bs in list_bs} for list_as in list_a}
```

^This comes out close to what I want but for some reason list_c's values aren't being iterated-- I've tried a for loop with them and still no luck.

Comment: are you should you want that result? and what is what you've tried to determine if a value in `list_b` should be paired up with what key from `list_b`? Same question for `list_c` in relation to `list_b` as keys.

Comment: The output format you're expecting doesn't quite make sense to me. Why is `'MACHINE TOOLS'` a level above the other keys found in the first list? If that's really what you want, then you're going to need to hardcode that value somewhere. But I'm thinking you may have meant to make each key in the first list appear in the top level?

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind your output ?

Comment: so to clearify it list_a would be the main keys  list_b would be sub keys of list_a and list_c would be the values. @nexus66

Comment: sorry I copied it wrong from my terminal. Its updated now @user3030010

Comment: I don't understand the ordering of `list_a`: is it not based on index?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, since the keys in the first dictionary don't line up with the keys in the second, it looks like you're first going to have to define a static mapping between some of these names. That would look something like:

```
name_mapping = {"MTOOLS": "MACHINE TOOLS",
                "FLUID": "FLUID",
                "VALVES": "VALVES"}
```

Then, create a blank version of the output dictionary.

```
output = {key:{} for key in set(list_a)}
```

And finally, update that dict with the values from the other two lists:

```
for inner_key, val in zip(list_b, list_c):
    for name, real_name in name_mapping.items():
        if inner_key.endswith(name):
            output[real_name][inner_key] = val
```

That results in this for the lists you presented:

```
{'FLUID': {'GROUP A FLUID': '46', 'GROUP B FLUID': '47'},
 'MACHINE TOOLS': {'GROUP A MTOOLS': '1',
                   'GROUP B MTOOLS': '2',
                   'GROUP C MTOOLS': '3',
                   'GROUP D MTOOLS': '44'},
 'VALVES': {'GROUP A VALVES': '52', 'GROUP B VALVES': '53'}}
```

If the values in your lists lined up (e.g. `'MACHINE TOOLS'` always appeared at the same index in `list_a` as something that ended with `'MTOOLS'` in `list_b`), then this solution could be simplified.